# Mock a mongoose document in Nestjs

Tags: mongodb, typescript, unit-testing, mongoose, nestjs

I'm trying to mock a mongoose document in my nestjs app to then use it in my unit test.

**fund.mock.ts**

```
import { Fund } from '../interfaces/fund.interface';

export const FundMock: Fund = {
  isin: 'FR0000000000',
  name: 'Test',
  currency: 'EUR',
  fund_type: 'uc',
  company: '5cf6697eecb759de13fc2c73',
  fed: true,
};
```

**fund.interface.ts**

```
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export interface Fund extends Document {
  isin: string;
  name: string;
  fed: boolean;
  currency: string;
  fund_type: string;
  company: string;
}
```

Logically it outputs an error that says that Document properties are missing.
`is missing the following properties from type 'Fund': increment, model, $isDeleted, remove, and 53 more.`

In my test I mock the getFund() method like so: 
`service.getFund = async () => FundMock;`

`getFund` expects to return `Promise<Fund>`

So how can I mock these properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mocked the `getFund` method in the wrong way. Here is the correct way to mock `getFund` method, you need to use `jest.fn` method to mock the method.

```
interface Fund {
  isin: string;
  name: string;
  fed: boolean;
  currency: string;
  fund_type: string;
  company: string;
}

export const FundMock: Fund = {
  isin: 'FR0000000000',
  name: 'Test',
  currency: 'EUR',
  fund_type: 'uc',
  company: '5cf6697eecb759de13fc2c73',
  fed: true
};

class Service {
  public async getFund() {
    return 'real fund data';
  }
}

export { Service };
```

Unit test:

```
import { Service, FundMock } from './';

const service = new Service();

describe('Service', () => {
  describe('#getFund', () => {
    it('t1', async () => {
      service.getFund = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(FundMock);
      const actualValue = await service.getFund();
      expect(actualValue).toEqual(FundMock);
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/mock-function/57492604/index.spec.ts
  Service
    #getFund
      ✓ t1 (15ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.464s
```

Comment: I don't know how to contact you directly. But thank you very much for all your help :) do you have a Twitter or any other social media account I can contact you with? Not to ask you more but to thank you directly.

Comment: @MattWalterspieler I have a GitHub :)